# Booleana a string en ASP clásico

Tags: asp, conversión-de-tipos, booleano, cast

Resulta que estamos haciendo una migración entre servidores y ahora estamos pasando nuestro código ASP clásico.

El caso es que en muchos sitios, tenemos comprobaciones del tipo

`if variablebooleana="True" then
...
end if`

El problema es que al servidor que estamos migrando tiene instalado el sistema operativo en castellano y por lo tanto al intentar hacer la conversión a string en lugar de devolver "True" devuelve "Verdadero".

¿Alguien sabe como configurar el iis para que devuelva "True" en estos casos?

Muchas gracias.

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Este proceso me funciono hace un par de años:

1. Desde el registro ( Inicio --> Ejecutar --> Regedit )
2. Buscar HKEY_USERS --> S-1-5-20 (Si es el usuario ASPNET) --> Control Panel --> International.
3. Desde aquí se puede ver la configuración regional del usuario y cambiarla.
4. Reiniciar IIS